# Electric dipole moment (EDM) and magnetic dipole moment (MDM): CP violation in neutron

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, beyond-the-standard-model, cp-violation

1. The [neutron magnetic dipole moment (MDM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_magnetic_moment) is the intrinsic magnetic dipole moment of the neutron.

- Under parity P, the MDM does not change direction.
- Under time reversal T which is equivalent to CP, the MDM does flip direction.

2. The [neutron electric dipole moment (EDM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_electric_dipole_moment) is the distribution of positive and negative charge inside the neutron. (Is it intrinsic?)

- Under time reversal T (or CP), the EDM does not change direction.
- Under parity P, the EDM does flip direction.

(The P and T=CP processes on MDM and EDM are shown below.)

### Questions

**What are the precise arguments and logic saying that the measurement of nonzero neutron electric dipole moment (EDM) implies CP violation?** (Since the EDM itself only violates P, but the EDM does not violate T = CP.)

Does this CP violation require that the neutron magnetic moment (MDM) is also nonzero? But then because the neutron MDM already breaks T = CP, then why do we need another EDM to break only P?

My guess is that because we want to have the MDM to break T = CP, while we must have the  EDM to break P, so it also breaks C or what? (It does not seem to be obvious.)

[Figure source Wiki page here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_electric_dipole_moment):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

What matter are not the behavior of the dipole moments $\vec{\mu}$ and $\vec{d}$ themselves, but the Hamiltonian terms $-\vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{B}$ and $-\vec{d}\cdot\vec{E}$,* showing the interactions of the moments with external fields.

Under parity, the electric field (being a polar vector) changes sign, but under time reversal, it does not.  (This can be understood by visualizing inverting the locations of all charges; this reverses the vector field $\vec{E}$ defined explicitly by Coulomb's Law.  However, inverting the direction of time does not reverse the explicit expression for $\vec{E}$, in which time does not appear.)  In contrast, under P, the magnetic field does not reverse sign, because the explicit formula for $\vec{B}$ is the Biot-Savart Law, which contains a cross product.  (Under $\vec{V}\rightarrow-\vec{V}$ and $\vec{W}\rightarrow-\vec{W}$, we hve $\vec{V}\times\vec{W}\rightarrow\vec{V}\times\vec{W}$, with the two minus signs canceling.  Thus the cross product of two vectors is a pseudovector or axial vector.)  However, the time reversal T inverts the directions of all currents while leaving the spatial configuration unchanged, which naturally reverses $\vec{B}$.

So the different transformation properties of $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ mean that the actual Hamiltonian/Lagrangian terms representing the dipole interactions have different discrete symmetries.  For the magnetic dipole, $\vec{B}$ changes sign under exactly the same combinations of C, P, and T as the spin vector (remembering that $\vec{\mu}=\mu\vec{\sigma}$ and $\vec{d}=d\vec{\sigma}$), so the combination $-\vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{B}$ is invariant under all the discrete symmetries.  However, the discrete symmetries of $\vec{\sigma}$ and $\vec{E}$ do not match up.  They are both odd under C; however, $\vec{\sigma}$ is P-even and T-odd, while $\vec{E}$ is P-odd and T-even, making $-\vec{d}\cdot\vec{E}$ odd under P, T, CP, and CT.

*Actually, these are the nonrelativistic limits of the general spin interactions with
$\mu\bar{\psi}\sigma^{\mu\nu}\psi F_{\mu\nu}$ and $d\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\bar{\psi}\sigma_{\mu\nu}\psi\tilde{F}_{\rho\sigma}$. In these forms, it is relatively straightforward to see that the electric dipole moment term must be odd under P and T, because of the presence of the Levi-Civita pseudo-tensor $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$.